# using two data tables in the same report

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, reporting-services

I'm working on an MVC .net web application, in my model I have a table called presence which contains a foreign key that references another table:

- presence(presence_id, **employee_id**, ...)
- employee (employee_id, employee_name, ...)

I want to display data in a report from those tables. Is it possible to use two data tables in the same report?
In fact I want a report that contains a table of all employees with all the correspending presences.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible, since you have a one to one connection I would take a look at [Lazy, Eager, and Explicit Loading of Related Data](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) (scroll down till you see that heading.)

In other situations where you just want to return multiple unrelated tables, all you have to do is make a view model (the same as a regular model) like this:

```
public class NewViewModel
{ 
    public Presence Presence { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

This would allow you to pass both tables from the controller to the view. This is not necessary in your case, I would guess, because it sounds like `Presence` is already added to `Employee`. So take a look at the link provided about how to load it and you should be able to access `Presence` like this `employee.presence`.

Comment: is correct, but I would suggest not to include database model classes (Presence & Employee) in ViewModel. Instead, You should include in ViewModel all and only columns You need in Your report. Going farther, it is good to return complex data types from service (repository) to ViewModel as DTO (data transfer object)